# why wordpress changes the order of the mathml tags

Tags: wordpress, mathml

I stored the following mathml code in database correctly. However, when it is displayed, seems wordpress changes the order of closing tag "mrow" inside "mfrac". So the rendered math expression is wrong.

This is the original mathml code:

```
<math>
    <mrow>
            <mi selected="true">f</mi>
            <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
            <mi>x</mi>
            <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
            <mo>=</mo>
            <mo>&minus;</mo>
            <mfrac>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                    <mrow>
                            <mn>1</mn>
                            <mo>+</mo>
                            <mrow>
                                    <mo>|</mo>
                                    <mi>x</mi>
                                    <mo>|</mo>
                            </mrow>
                    </mrow>
            </mfrac>
            <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
            <mi>x</mi>
            <mo>&isin;</mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
    </mrow>
</math>
```

This is the html code rendered in browser:

```
 <math>
    <mrow>
            <mi selected="true">f</mi>
            <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
            <mi>x</mi>
            <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
            <mo>=</mo>
            <mo>&minus;</mo>
            <mfrac>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                    <mrow>
                        <mn>1</mn>
                        <mo>+</mo>
                     </mrow>
                     <mrow>
                        <mo>|</mo>
                        <mi>x</mi>
                        <mo>|</mo>
                    </mrow>
            </mfrac>
            <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
            <mi>x</mi>
            <mo>&isin;</mo>
            <mi>R</mi>
            <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
    </mrow>
</math>
```

Comment: your initial mathml has an invalid select attribute but that probably isn't related. What browser are you using? old versions of Chrome (7 and 8 I think) mis-parsed mested mrows in mathml but that was fixed a while back

Comment: My chrome version is 21.0.1180.83 m. I don't think this is caused by browser.

Answer (score 0):

`mrow` and `mfrac` are on the same level of the MathML tag hierarchy, which is called the presentation layout schemata, so maybe the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd) is being misinterpreted to disallow nested `mrow`s:

> Recursive definition for content of expressions. Include
>        presentation constructs at lowest level so presentation
>        layout schemata hold presentation or content elements.
>        Include content constructs at lowest level so content
>        elements hold PCDATA or presentation elements at leaf
>        level (for permitted substitutable elements in context)

May also be related to an [existing bug](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13340).

Comment: nested `mrow`s are not invalid.